# Convert a split string to a tuple results in "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, string, for-loop, split, iterable-unpacking

Using split in a for loop results in the mentioned exception. But when taking the elements indpendent from a for loop it works:

```
>>> for k,v in x.split("="):
...   print k,v
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> y =  x.split("=")
>>> y
['abc', 'asflskfjla']
>>> k,v = y
>>> k
'abc'
>>> v
'asflskfjla'
```

An explanation would be appreciated - and also naturally the proper syntax for the for loop version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `for` loop expects that each item in the iterable can be unpacked into two variables. So in your case, it'd look something like one of these:

```
[('a, b'), ('c, d'), ...]
[['a, b'], ['c, d'], ...]
['ab', 'cd', ...]
...
```

Each item in each of those iterables can be split up into a `k` and a `v` component. In your case, they cannot, as the output of `x.split('=')` is a list of strings with more than two characters:

```
['abc', 'asflskfjla']
```

Comment: I wouldn't say two-tuple -- Maybe sequence of length 2 (although even that may not be good enough ...)

Comment: @mgilson: I have to work on that terminology. Something like this?

Comment: Yeah.  that's about as good as you can do it I think.  (generators yielding 2 items also work, so that breaks my terminology with sequences).

Answer (score 3):

`x.split` returns a list of strings, as you can see from your `y` variable.  When you iterate over that, it takes the first element of the list `'abc'` and tries to bind it to the tuple `k, v`.  Since strings are a sequence type, it tries to assign the characters of the string to the tuple you've asked for - and there are in fact too many values (three letters) to unpack into a two-element tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted this behavior just wrap `s.split()` in a list:

```
>>> for (k,v) in [s.split("=")]:
    print(k,v)  
('abc', 'asflskfjla')
```