# Too many values to unpack in python: Caused by the file format

Tags: python, file, foreach, valueerror

I have two files, which have two columns as following:

```
file 1
------
main 46
tag  23
bear 15
moon 2

file 2
------
main 20
rocky 6
zoo 4
bear 2
```

I am trying to compare the first 2 rows of each file together and in case there are some words that are the same, I will sum up the numbers and write those in a new file.

I read the file and used a foreach loop to go through each line, but it returns a ValueError:too many values to unpack.

```
import os
from itertools import islice
DIR = r'dir'
for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    with open(os.path.sep.join([DIR, filename]), 'r') as f:
        for i in range(2):
            line = f.readline().strip()
            word, freq = line.split():
                print(word)
                print(count)
```

In the file, there is an extra empty line after each line of the text. I searched for the \n; but nothing is there.
then I removed them manually and then it worked.

Comment: `lines.split()` returns a list. So, you are trying to unpack into two variables when in for loop it returns one element at a time

Comment: Do the files start with the `word | count` line?

Comment: how I can get two variables?

Comment: Use `word, freq = line.split()` but this will fail if `.split` returns a list with less than or more than two items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620136/convert-a-split-string-to-a-tuple-results-in-too-many-values-to-unpack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a split string to a tuple results in "too many values to unpack"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620136/convert-a-split-string-to-a-tuple-results-in-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Comment: no, it does not have any heade

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks.  there is a line, between lines in the file. when I check with \n search from the editor, it does not find any.
but if I delete them manually your script works

Comment: @Raha1986 since it is whitespace, and you've `.strip`ped the line, you can just check `if line:`

Comment: @AnanthRao  It is not the same problem. maybe there are more to unpack but I cannot see them in the file. that is the problem

Comment: @Prune:  It is not the same problem. maybe there are more to unpack but I cannot see them in the file. that is the problem

Comment: Then you need to update the problem specification.  If you have a variable quantity of things to unpack, you need more than the current logic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the answer. but what should I check, if 
 I cannot recognize what is there. I checked the file.

Comment: The `file 1` example you posted clearly has a blank line in it. How you do want to treat that case? You say you are trying to compare the first two rows so obviously there is an error in the file. Is that a permanent error that should result in failure? Do you want to advance through the file until you find a line?

Comment: @Raha1986 I think you're a little confused on what it is trying to unpack. The reason it thinks there are 4 values to unpack is because "main" has 4 letters. Look carefully at the answer to the question I linked

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many items you have in the line, then you can't use the nice *unpack* facility.  You'll need to split and check how many you got.  For instance:

```
with open(os.path.sep.join([DIR, filename]), 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        if len(data) >= 2:
            word, count = line[:2]
```

This will get you the first two fields of any line containing at least that many.  Since you haven't specified what to do with other lines or extra fields, I'll leave that (any **else** part) up to you.  I've also left out the **strip** part to accent the existing code; line input and **split** will get rid of newlines and spaces, but not necessarily all white space.

Comment: so do you mean what is between the lines of text is whitespace?

Comment: No; I mean that you went to extra trouble to **strip** each argument.  Since **split** removes spaces in the line, using **strip** implies that you're worried about other white space staying in the input strings.

Comment: even if use strip or not, I get the same Error. As I edited my problem statement, there is a line between lines of text. when I erased manually, the code does not return any error.

Comment: In which case, the **if** statement looking for at least two fields will guard your interests.  The issue in your comment wasn't the black line, but the need for **strip**.