# "ValueError too many values to unpack" when using str.split in a for loop

Tags: python, split, valueerror, iterable-unpacking

I've gotten this error before where the cause was obvious, but I'm having trouble with this snippet below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ACL = 'group:troubleshooters:r,user:auto:rx,user:nrpe:r'

for e in ACL.split(','):
  print 'e = "%s"' % e
  print 'type during split = %s' % type(e.split(':'))
  print 'value during split:  %s' % e.split(':')
  print 'number of elements:  %d' % len(e.split(':'))
  for (one, two, three) in e.split(':'):
      print 'one = "%s", two = "%s"' % (one, two)
```

I've added those print statements for debugging, and have confirmed that the split is producing a 3-element list, but when I try to put that into 3 variables, I get:

```
e = "group:troubleshooters:r"
type during split = <type 'list'>
value during split:  ['group', 'troubleshooters', 'r']
number of elements:  3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/python_split_test.py", line 10, in <module>
for (one, two, three) in e.split(':'):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a split string to a tuple results in "too many values to unpack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620136/convert-a-split-string-to-a-tuple-results-in-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should:

```
one, two, three = e.split(":")
```

as `e.split(":")` is already an iterable with three values.

If you write

```
for (one, two, three) in something
```

Then `something` must be an iterable of iterable of three values, e.g. `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, but not `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (one, two, three) in e.split(':'):
```

requires `e.split()` to return a list of iterables (e.g. a 2-dimensional list). `for` will iterate over the list, and assign each element of the nested list to the coresponding variables during that iteration.

But `e.split()` just returns a single list of strings. You don't need to iterate, just assign them:

```
one, two, three = e.split(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
one, two, three = e.split(':')
print 'one = "%s", two = "%s"' % (one, two)
```