# Failure converting complex code to a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

**NB**: None of the suggested answers work for me as they are for-loop driven (which I already have working) and don't explain what is wrong with the list comprehension version.

---

I am trying to transform

```
('name:80', 'desc:100')
```

into

```
{'name': 80, 'desc': 100}
```

A working `for`-loop:

```
new_wrap = {}
for item in wrap:
    k, v = item.split(':')
    new_wrap[k] = int(v)
wrap = new_wrap
```

a non-working list-comprehension:

```
wrap = dict([
    (k, int(v))
    for item in wrap
    for (k, v) in item.split(':')
    ])
```

which gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line ..., in ...
    for (k, v) in item.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dict(map('{:s}:{:d}'.parse, wrap))`. I wish! :) (not even joking, I could've used that quite often)

Comment: @StefanPochmann You can actually get pretty close to that with [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/).  It won't monkeypatch a method onto `str`, but it will be nice enough: `dict(parse('{}:{:d}', w).fixed for w in wrap)`

Comment: @wim Nice, though I think most cases for me were on SO, and I wouldn't want to have to tell people to install that (unless string parsing is what their question is about).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a split string to a tuple results in "too many values to unpack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620136/convert-a-split-string-to-a-tuple-results-in-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Comment: Also: [“ValueError too many values to unpack” when using str.split in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50054003/7851470)

Comment: Duplicate for strings to dict conversion (also has an answer with comprehension): [Convert list of strings to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980977/convert-list-of-strings-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the insight provided by John Kugelman I was able to figure out the problem and the solution I wanted.

---

The working code from the `for` loop:

```
k, v = item.split(':')
```

Breakdown:

- `item.split(':') == 'name:80'.split(':') == 'name', '80'`
- `k, v = 'name', '80'`
- `k == 'name' and v == 80`

The non-working code in the `list-comp`:

```
for (k, v) in item.split(':')
```

Breakdown:

- `item.split(':') == 'name:80'.split(':') == 'name', '80'`
- `for (k, v) in ('name', '80')`

And there's the problem:  `in` *is not the same as* `=`.  `in` iterates over its arguments, returning one at a time, so:

- `k, v = 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'` is what is attempted, and because four items are trying to be stuffed into two we get the `ValueError: too many values to unpack` exception.

The simple solution is to encapsulate the `item.split()` into a tuple of its own:

- `for k, v in (item.split(':'), )`

which becomes

- `for k, v in (('name', '80'), )`

and since the first item in the tuple is a tuple we get

- `k, v = 'name', '80'` for the first (and only) iteration of the second `for` loop

and the problem is solved without nesting another `list-comp` inside the primary `list-comp`.

The final, working `list-comp`:

```
    [
    (k, int(v))
    for item in wrap
    for (k, v) in (item.split(':'), )
    ]
```

Comment: Whatever reason you have to insist on your list comprehension, but that's unreadable and ugly compared to the dict comprehension provided in @John Kugelman 's answer. Which should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: @Jeronimo: the `list-comp` is shown at the end because that is where the problem was and where I could show the solution.  The actual code in use does use the dict/generator approach as outlined by John Kugelman.  John is getting the bounty because his answer explained what I had done wrong; this is the accepted answer because it goes into detail about what went wrong, why, and has a solution that doesn't nest one comprehension inside another.

Answer (score 11):

You don't want to *iterate* over `item.split(':')`, you want to *unpack* it. To do that you can introduce a nested comprehension or generator expression. That gives you an opportunity to create the new variables `k` and `v`:

```
dict([
    (k, int(v))
    for k,v in (item.split(':') for item in wrap)
    ])
```

I would then get rid of the square brackets. It's more efficient to use a generator expression that generates entries on the fly rather than a list comprehension that builds a whole list in memory just to throw it away when the dict is created.

```
dict((k, int(v))
     for k,v in (item.split(':') for item in wrap))
```

You simplify it even further by using a dict comprehension with curly braces:

```
{k: int(v) for k,v in (item.split(':') for item in wrap)}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to stick to a comprehension that's one-level deep and don't mind using Python 3.8+, you can use an assignment expression to hold the result of the split in a variable for indexing:

```
{(t := s.split(':'))[0]: int(t[1]) for s in wrap}
```

Comment: It's cool that this works, but I would hate to see it in production code!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should separate splitting from conversion to an int:

```
{k: int(v) for k, v in [w.split(":") for w in wrap]}
#{'name': 80, 'desc': 100}
```

But, as *roganjosh* correctly suggested, you gain nothing from this.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution:

`x = ('name:80', 'desc:100')
dict([tuple(a.split(':')) for a in x])`

Comment: This doesn't covert the string `"80"` into the number `80`.

Comment: change second line: dict([tuple([a.split(':')[0], int(a.split(':')[1])]) for a in x])